# need to print a number when clicked one by one

Tags: javascript

I am making a calculator with pure javascript. I need the number inside the button to print out if I click the button once. like if I click 1 it should display 1 on my screen and if I clicked 2 it should display 2 on my screen. only the number 2 without 1...

```
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
<button>4</button>
<button>5</button>
<button>6</button>
<button>6</button>
<button>8</button>
<button>9</button>
<button>10</button>
```

how can I do that without the onclick event?

Comment: How do you expect to capture button click events without using a listener?

Comment: i wanted to do with addEventListener not with ```onclick="myFunciton()"```

Comment: That would have been useful information to have in the question.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const display = document.getElementById('display')
document.getElementById('buttons').addEventListener('click', ({target}) => {
  console.log(target.innerText)
  display.innerHTML = target.innerText;
})
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
  <button>4</button>
  <button>5</button>
  <button>6</button>
  <button>6</button>
  <button>8</button>
  <button>9</button>
  <button>10</button>
</div>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: Might be useful to explain what [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) is, and how you're using it. But this is the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`document.querySlectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). This will give nodelist, then iterate through it and add event listener , so that on click it displays the text content to a display area

```js
const displayContainer = document.getElementById('display')
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    displayContainer.innerHTML = e.target.textContent.trim();
  })
})
```

```html
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
<button>4</button>
<button>5</button>
<button>6</button>
<button>6</button>
<button>8</button>
<button>9</button>
<button>10</button>
<div id='display'></div>
```

Comment: i expect this answer only thanks to @brk

Answer (score 1):

This should get you going.

- Use [`querySelectorAll`] to select all the buttons.
- Add [`eventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to all the buttons.
- Use `event.target` to get the value of button and make the logic from
  there.

```js
const h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
const btns = document.querySelectorAll("button");
btns.forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', event => {
    h1.textContent = event.target.textContent;
  });
});
```

```html
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
<button>4</button>
<button>5</button>
<button>6</button>
<button>6</button>
<button>8</button>
<button>9</button>
<button>0</button>

<h1></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

assign id to button and then use listener to handle click like this

```
<button id='btn1'>Hello</button>


var button = document.getElementById("btn1");
button.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    console.log("button pressed")
},false);
```